# Mediawiki Multilevel Transclusion

Tags: templates, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I am using Mediawiki to try and format a few articles so that they flow together logically.  Here is what I have an what I am getting:

Template A is the base template

Page B is a page that uses Template A

Page C is a page that transcludes a part of Page B

I have, in Template A:

```
<onlyinclude>

  <includeonly>'''Role'''</includeonly>
  {{{role}}}
</onlyinclude>
```

In Page B:

```
{{PageB|role=Admin}}  //Page B combined to avoid whitespace questions
```

Page C:

```
{{:PageB}}  //Again name combined in order to avoid whitespace questions
```

Results:

I get the expected results on Page C which is the "role" portion of Page B.

The part that I get that I DON'T want is that Page B now ONLY has the "role" piece of Template A.

Desired:

What I would like to happen is for Page B to show ALL of Template A and for Page C to only transclude the part of Page B that I'm interested in.  Aside from putting  around each instance of Page B (Template A  was made as a...template...for all variations of Page B) that I want to include when Page B is transcluded, how can I do this using the template (Template A)?  Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, without adding checks for page name or something like that. The tags you're using don't have options to work differently when they're transcluded directly than when they're transcluded indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, however, let's see if we can clarify.  You have `Template:Role` with the content of:

```
<onlyinclude><includeonly>'''Role'''</includeonly>{{{role}}}</onlyinclude>
```

Which should return:

**Role** {{{role}}}

You also have `Page_B` with the content of:

```
B Some text<br />
{{Role|role=Admin}}<br />
B Some more text<br />
B And more text
```

Which should come out looking like:

B Some text
**Role** Admin
B Some more text
B And more text

Then, you have `Page_C` with the content of:

```
{{:Page_B}}<br />
C Some text<br />
C Some more text
```

Which would come out like:

B Some text
**Role** Admin
B Some more text
B And more text
C Some text
C Some more text

But! You want it to come out like:

**Role** Admin
B Some more text
C Some text
C Some more text

If this is correct, your understanding of `<noinclude>`, `<onlyinclude>`, and `<includeonly>` is slightly skewed.  `<noinclude>` is used to keep the content within ONLY on the page the it is written on, will not be transcluded.. `<onlyinclude>`is useful mostly for controlling what get's passed on through a template.. Helps in defining for the editor what is going to be transcluded.  It helps in setting boundaries for white space and unwanted line-feeds. Content between a set `<includeonly>` tags prevents that content from being seen on the page it is written, and only seen on the transcluded page.

So, `Template:Role` would have to look like this instead:

```
<onlyinclude>'''Role'''{{{role}}}</onlyinclude>
```

And, `Page_B` would have to look like this instead:

```
B Some text<br />
<onlyinclude>{{Role|role=Admin}}<br />
B Some more text<br /></onlyinclude>
B And more text
```

I hope this satisfies your question and is helpful for you.